# Confused about Mongoose/Mongo Terminology. Are Sub-Docs/Embedded-Docs also Collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have the following mongoose models:

```
// child.model.js
var mongoose      = require('mongoose'),
    Schema        = mongoose.Schema,
    childSchema   = new Schema({

        name: String,
        age: Number

    }, {collection: 'children'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Child', childSchema);

//parent.model.js
var mongoose      = require('mongoose'),
    Child         = require('./child.model.js'),
    Schema        = mongoose.Schema,
    parentSchema  = new Schema({

        name: String,
        children: [Child.schema]

    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
```

Would this mean I would then have two collections, one called 'parents' and one called 'children'?

As I currently understand it the above code creates a nested document structure whereby the `Child` objects exist only within the collection of `Parent` documents. However, I'm getting confused by the `{collection: 'name'}` option that you can pass to the `Schema` constructor. Is this option just ignored when creating sub-documents like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of subdocs - [Embedded](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) and [Referenced](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). This is a Mongoose-level classification. At MongoDB level it's just [Collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-collection) and [Documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-document).

The difference between Embedded and Referenced docs in Mongoose is that the former is akin to having the child schema "embedded" in the parent. I.e. as far as MongoDB is concerned it (Parent) is just a one big document.

Whereas in referenced docs the Parent document only stores the child document's ObjectID, i.e. the child document is "referenced", and it's left up to you to "[populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)" the entire document.

What you're using `children: [Child.schema]` is the syntax of an Embedded document.

> Would this mean I would then have two collections, one called 'parents' and one called 'children'?

So you'll have only 1 collection in MongoDB.

> However, I'm getting confused by the {collection: 'name'} option that you can pass to the Schema constructor. Is this option just ignored when creating sub-documents like this?

[That option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) is just so that if you were to actually create a model from that schema, it uses the name you provided instead of automatically inferring.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I thought that might be the case. Although, I'm still curious as to what happens when you pass that collection name option. I guess it is just ignored? Or maybe it would come into play if used the Child model separately from the Parent model in which case maybe it does create a collection in MongoDB? I guess I will just have to experiment. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MattHerbstritt Yes, exactly. That option is just so that if you were to actually create a model from that schema, it uses the name you provided instead of automatically inferring.