# Simple Mongodb embedded database structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want to build a `Mongodb` database (Mongoose/Node.js) structure but i face a problem right now. i have two entities. `Users` and `Books` and i want to use embedded system(because of lack of joins in mongodb). And my problem is that which of this entities shpuld be an inner value to other.

For example i wiil face this two type of query in my app:

```
1- Books of an specific user
2- Users of an specific book
```

Now, Books should be a inner value for Users or contrariwise?

i can do this two:

Users schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    use_name: String,
    user_family: String,
    user_books: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'books' }
});
```

Or this:

Books Schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    book_name: String,
    book_lang: String,
    book_user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'users' }
});
```

which is better? which is standard approach?

if i use both of them, when saving i have to do two save operation. if i has a large database with a lots of collections its gets worse that this...

after a lot of research i find out i have to use embedded system rather that using relation like collections to connect entities to each other, because Mongodb doesn't support joins and has poor support of things like this. embedded system is the correct way for a NoSql database like Mongodb?

Comment: In your example you have referenced docs, not embedded. [Checkout the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487042/confused-about-mongoose-mongo-terminology-are-sub-docs-embedded-docs-also-colle/31487318#31487318). And yes, Mongo works best when you're using embedded documents so that all books in a user will be fetched along in just 1 query, instead of references in which you'll have to populate (the join equivalent).

Comment: @laggingreflex:  there is some problems in referencing mode. i have to do two save operations per one user input, one for saving document itself and one for adding it's object id as reference to other document. is this relevant in mongodb? is this a good structure at all? another problem is querying, for example i need to fetch users that reads an specific book, i have to query on Users collection and populate books for each of them and check if each of them has that book or not and in the end in the result i have some users with null value for books. imagine i have 1 million users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there's a minor correction that your `user_books` needs to be an array [].

Secondly, you should only reference one schema into another, otherwise you'll have to add unnecessary complexity in keeping them in sync.

So here's what your schemas should look like:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    use_name: String,
    user_family: String,
    user_books: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'books' }]
});

var BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    book_name: String,
    book_lang: String,
});
```

Now "to fetch users that reads an specific book", you'll query like this:

```
UserSchema.find({ user_books: book._id })
```

which will give you all users that have `BOOK_ID` as (at least) one of their books.

If that's all, I guess you don't need population at all then.

---

Updated on the issue with $elemMatch query not working:

So as it turned out, we don't actually need $elemMatch with referenced docs array, since it's a simple array of _ids.

```
user // =>
{
    _id: 56351c611ca0d2e81274100a
    name: ...
    books: [56351c611ca0d2e81274100b, 56351c611ca0d2e81274100c, ...]
}
```

`$elemMatch` works with **array of objects**, and would've been in the case of **embedded doc**:

```
var BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    book_name: String,
    book_lang: String,
});


var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    use_name: String,
    user_family: String,
    user_books: [BookSchema]
});
```

Since in this case the document would be like this:

```
user // =>
{
    _id: 56351c611ca0d2e81274100a
    name: ...
    books: [
             { // each book here has an _id: 
               _id: 56351c611ca0d2e81274100b,
               // this is what `$elemMatch: {_id:` would match for
               name: ...
               // you could do `$elemMatch: {name:`
               lang: ...
               // or `$elemMatch: {lang:`
             }, {
               _id: 56351c611ca0d2e81274100c,
               name: ...
               lang: ...
             }, ...
           ]
}
```

This is where $elemMatch query would be needed.

```
UserSchema.find({ user_books: {$elemMatch: {_id: book._id } } })
```

Comment: that elemMatch query you wrote results is 'undefined' for me. whats that _id there? i just store an Object id's of books in UserSchema and i wont populate it yet.

Comment: i use this format: UserSchema.find().exec(function(err,result){});  and i get undefined for 'result' value. i use your format too, still undefined. i use Mongoose 4.0.2. but whats that _id there? we don't have any populate still

Comment: i get this message in 'err': [Error: Can't use $elemMatch with ObjectId.]

Comment: i give it an string like this:{ $elemMatch: { _id: '563220da27cf8edc2b9a3936' } }}. im testing and i know book id is this in database.

Comment: Try this: `UserSchema.find({ user_books: book._id })` without `$elemMatch`

Comment: this works. but yesterday i was trying to wrk with eleMatch it doesn't work

Comment: if i change it to this, works: {$elemMatch:{$in:['563220da27cf8edc2b9a3936']}} . i still don't know whats that _id there. and i have another question, we drop objectId  type and ref from schema, later if we want do populate on this, it works?

Comment: Yes. And populate only works on ref docs. Embedded docs are already pre-populated, as seen above

Comment: thanks for your attention. i have to read lots more and right now my question resolved i think.